# 2D toric code intuition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, gauge-theory, lattice-gauge-theory

I’m trying to self-learn QFT in condensed matter and I’ve hit a stumbling block with gauge theory and toric code. I’m trying to solve problem 2 from this webpage http://www.its.caltech.edu/~motrunch/Teaching/Phy127c_Spring14/HW4.pdf

Where they ask to prove the ground state of this Hamiltonian

\begin{aligned}
&H=-\alpha \sum_{r} \hat{A}_{r}-\beta \sum_{P} \hat{B}_{P}\\
&\hat{A}_{r}=\prod_{r^{\prime} \in r} \hat{\sigma}_{r r^{\prime}}^{x}, \quad \hat{B}_{P}=\hat{\sigma}_{12}^{z} \hat{\sigma}_{23}^{z} \hat{\sigma}_{34}^{z} \hat{\sigma}_{41}^{z}
\end{aligned}

Is this wave function

$$\left|\Psi_{0}\right\rangle=\sum_{\left\{S_{r r^{\prime}}^{x}\right\} \text { satisfying } \prod_{r^{\prime} \in r} S_{r r^{\prime}}^{x}=1 \text { for every } r}\left|\left\{S_{r r^{\prime}}^{x}\right\}\right\rangle$$

I’m a little lost as far as intuition goes. My understanding is that the ground state is the collection of eigenvectors such that the product of spins on the 4 star/vertex operator sites is positive. That’s fine, so I could have something of the form $$|(1,1,1,1),(1,-1,-1,1),(-1,-1,-1,-1),(-1,-1,1,1),...\rangle$$ Where the product of the four entries in each eigenvector needs to be positive (more precisely equal to 1).

Now to test that this is the ground state... I’m not sure. I could find the expectation value of the Hamiltonian, but without knowing the ground state energy prior, I couldn’t really conclude that I have the ground state. Also, I’m confused how $\sigma^z$s would act on the eigenvectors. I know that one of these operators would give us a spin flip, which I’m inclined to believe is the $\sigma^z$, but since I’m in the $\sigma^x$ basis, this point is confusing as well. Any elucidation would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I also know that since plaquette and vertex operators commute, that the Hamiltonian can be simultaneously diagonalized. This seems important but I’m still struggling with operating on this ground state.

Comment: The point made in your edit is really crucial. Since the Hamiltonian, all plaquette operators, and all vertex operators commute, you are free to replace the plaquette/vertex operators with their eigenvalues. What are the possible eigenvalues for these operators? (There is no need to consider the individual $\sigma$'s, just work with the plaquette/vertex operators.)